# Read negative voltages with an MCP3008

Tags: voltage, analog, adc

[image: buck boost converter]

How can I read a negative voltages with the [MCP3008](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21295d.pdf)?
I tried to do that with this code but I could not read
them; the largest readings are 0.00.

This is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pigpio
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
 exit()

def analogInput(channel):
 spi.max_speed_hz = 1442      #f_cpu/frequency 1442
 adc=spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
 data = ((adc[1]&3)<<8) + adc[2]
 return data

def Volts(data):
 volts=(data*3.3)/float(1023)      #1024
 volts=round(volts,2)
 return volts  

dc=718000
pi.hardware_PWM(18, 70000, dc) 
while True:
 out = analogInput(0)
 out1 = Volts(out)
 print(out1)
 time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: It cannot. BUT! Maybe you can make a circuit which converts it to a positive voltage instead! Where is the negative voltage coming from? Add a schematic if necessary.

Comment: @user253751 this is my buck boost converter , i get in the output -12V to -9V, i want to read this voltages and do with it something

Comment: @user253751 in the schematic that you posted the output is the input of the mcp3008?

Comment: yes............

Comment: @user253751 i connect like you said , but i get a zeros in the reading

Comment: What voltage did you measure at the ADC input?

Comment: @user253751 the voltage start from 1.9V and then goes to zero

Comment: @user253751 when i have -10.77V voltage at the output of the converter, i get at the input of ADC 3.3/3.2V,why?my resistors are : R1=25K and R2=75K , By calculations I should get 0.6075V

Answer (score 1):

It cannot.

However, you can make a voltage divider that will make it into a positive voltage, by using a positive voltage as one side of your divider.

You say the voltage you want to measure is -12V to -9V. If you have +3.3V available, you could use a voltage divider with about a 4:1 ratio, like so (4.7:1 in this case):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkMloP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your output voltage will be $$V_{out} = 3.3 + \frac{10}{57}V_{in}$$

So when the input is -12V, the output will be 1.195V. When the input is -9V, the output will be 1.721V.

If you have a different voltage than +3.3V or your ADC can only measure up to 1V or something, you'll need different resistor values, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Your schematic is large because it is narrow (compared to its height).  The size it uses seems to be set by the width.  Try dragging your output further out and rotating the labels on the left so they stick out that way...the whole thing will shrink.

Comment: .... thus cutting your sensitivity by a factor of almost 6